# Trying to understand Google Results and meta tags

Tags: seo, meta-tags, google-search, meta

*Note: this does NOT regard ranking, I just want the results to look better overall.*

I'm working with a "news site" with a lot of articles, some dynamic, some static. 
The developers haven't really given much thought about SEO but now want the Google Results to look a bit prettier - which landed on my table.

In the source code there's a few meta-tags, example:

```
<meta name="twitter:title" content="content">
<meta name="og:title" content="content">
```

Running it through Google Structured Data Testing Tool shows what I'd expect but it doesn't look like my search result for that specific link has the correct snippet.
Seems like it doesn't want to pick the og:description content all the time. **Sometimes it does**, and sometimes it also adds the **title again** in the snippet.

What I don't get: is Google using og:title for results or is that only for ex Facebook sharing? Do I simply need this one below, since that is actually missing from the code?
The description itself would be the same as og:description since they contain the same content.

```
<meta name="description" content="content">
```

As far as I understand it can be quite tricky to customize these sorts of things but could it really be that hard to have any sort of consistency throughout the results from our page?

Comment: What kind of snippet do they want to get?

Comment: @unor Lines from that specific article. Another news site has a pretty good view of their results and we want something similar but ours sometimes get cut of like "... and then this happened and this and this" while the other get "While this happened and then this happened and this and this".
I want some sort of consistency but I'm not sure how to approach it.

Answer (score -1):

There are two things you can do but both come with a caveat.

Google takes anything from your site as a **suggestion**. There is no way to program it to perform identically in all situations. If Google's algorithm believes there is a better way to present a result - it will ignore any direction you give it and auto-generate a new presentation for your page.

That said there's two things you can do:

1. Add meta tags with the exact text you'd like to appear on the SERP. The page title may or may not be appended with your brand/company name. If it already contains the company/brand name, Google is more likely to leave it where it is.
2. Google takes text from the page based on what it thinks is more important/relevant to the search. For News, using either HTML5 elements (nav, article, aside) or labelling your divs with a class using those key words will help Google understand what the *real* content is. Asides are less likely to be used while Articles will be focused upon.

I would also recommend having authors write their own custom descriptions and insert them with your CMS. They're likely much better at constructing a good summary than Google or an auto-summary script. Google will experiment with alt descriptions occasionally but once something solidifies itself as popular in terms of click rate, it'll stick.